# Why does ServiceStack not implement the ruleSet optional parameter in the Validate method?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

Why does ServiceStack not implement the **ruleSet** optional parameter in the Validate method?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I have found you can call it by casting to AbstractValidator

```
var validator = new PersonValidator();
var person = new Person();
var result = ((AbstractValidator<Person>)validator).Validate(person, ruleSet: "Names");
```

It seems that form of IValidator.Validate() is an extension method, so you could instead add a using statement to your cs file, and it should work as-is.

```
using ServiceStack.FluentValidation;
```